# Copy all files to one folder using CMD

Tags: windows-xp, batch

I want to collect all images and movies in one folder. I try to type in Windows XP CMD:

```
set nowy="c:\nowy"
mkdir %nowy% 
for /R %f in (*.mpg *.swf *.jpg) DO (copy "%f" %nowy%)
```

but it seems that if I am on `C%cd%=C:)`, the system tries to copy files also from... `c:\nowy` to `c:\nowy` and it's asking if they should be overwritten.

Is there a more convenient way?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but you can suppress that prompt with `copy /Y "%f" %nowy%`